# Ubuntu 20.04 Port 465

Tags: mail

I've tried running the following. However, port 465 is still closed when I used an online port checker to test. Is there another way on Ubuntu to open this SMTP port?
`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT` 
`sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT` 
`sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 465 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Generally `ufw` is the tool to use when making changes you your `iptables`. Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo ufw status`? This will list which ports are available from where.

Comment: `sudo ufw status` returns: `sudo: ufw: command not found`

Comment: Are you sure you’re running Ubuntu? What does `sudo lsb_release -a` output?

Comment: It says ```Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal```

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server running on port 465? If should show with this command: netstat - tunlp